# How does Windows Search operate over the network?

Tags: windows, network-share

Lets say I have two machines, A and B.

I pop open a drive in B from A:

`\\B$c\somefolder`

Then I enter a term to search in the menu "foo."
[image: screenshot of search filter menu]

Does the search on my machine consist of A searching all the contents of 
`\\B$c\somefolder` or is there an inter-process communication that occurs where A sends a message (perhaps by remote procedure call) to B in order to offload the processing?

Comment: That depends on whether the remote machine is a server running the Windows Indexing/Search Service.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer exactly how this works, but I played around a little and discovered that if I opened a shared drive in windows explorer and did a search in the folder (as with the screenshot you reference) explorer.exe on the local machine becomes active and stays active for the duration of the search, but there is no corresponding activity on the remote machine which I was monitoring in an RDP session. So it seems like the processing is done locally.